# What is the URL length limit for OneLogin REST API endpoints?

Tags: onelogin

I'm using OneLogin's Java SDK/Client to retrieve Events, Users, Groups and User Roles data.

I'm wondering if there is a URL length limit because the REST API endpoints to get data are invoked using HTTP GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you gonna have problems with the queries you build.

OneLogin supports SAML, and the SAML Messages length is kinda big.

Comment: I'm not referring to OneLogin's SSO. I'm referring to their REST API that I can access using their java client SDK. Their is probably a limitation because the URLs are sent as GET requests.

Comment: I know you were not referring to SSO, but I said that on SSO using HTTP-Redirect binding, there are GET parameter that its length is long an is supported, so you will not experience issues due length limit.